# Node.js Reacting weird in IF Condition

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have function to check if key exists or not so the below if i do console.log it returns null not true||false on Live server but on my MAC OSX local it works file

```
 console.log((key=='parent' && atts.filters[key]))  //returns null not true||false
 if(key=='parent' && atts.filters[key]) {         
    atts.filters[key] = 'demo'
 }
```

So can anybody helps to figure it out what wrong here ?

Comment: so `atts.filters[key]` is null, so you won't go into the if statement since `null` is `falsy`

Comment: try `!!atts.filters[key]`

Comment: `null` is falsey in Javascript and will evaluate to `false` in the if condition.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are truthy, `a && b && c` will evaluate to `c`. If you want to force a boolean result, use only boolean expressions. Try `key == "parent" && atts.filters.hasOwnProperty(key)`

Answer (score 1):

[Logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

> Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values. When they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the `&&` and `||` operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so **if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may return a non-Boolean value**.

If `atts.filters[key]` returns `null` or empty string, you can use [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) to convert the value:

```js
var key = 'parent';
console.log((key=='parent' && Boolean(null)))
console.log((key=='parent' && Boolean('')))
```

Answer (score 0):

atts.filters[key] might be returning null

```js
console.log(true && null) //null
```